# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(e^{-2\pi in/m}\right)^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometric-series

Let $k,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and consider $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(e^{-2\pi in/m}\right)^k$. I was wondering why
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(e^{-2\pi in/m}\right)^k =
\begin{cases}
m , \ \ \ \ \ \ n/m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
0 , \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n/m \notin \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}
$$
I understand this is actually a geometric series, so
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(e^{-2\pi in/m}\right)^k = \frac{1- e^{-2in}}{1- e^{-2in/m}}.$$
This fraction can only be zero if and only if $e^{-2\pi in} =1$. But I don't see the reason why this is true. Furthermore, how come that the sum is equal to $m$ when $n/m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does it mean that $\left(e^{-2\pi in/m}\right)^k = 1$ when $n/m \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: This is not true since some $\pi$ are missing from the equations.

Comment: You are right. I've edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(e^{-2\pi in/m})^k=m[m|n]$ (for brevity I've used an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)), separately consider the case $m|n$ for which the sum is $\sum_k1=m$, and the case$$m\nmid n\implies e^{-2\pi in/m}\ne1\implies\frac{\color{blue}{1-e^{-2\pi in}}}{\color{red}{1-e^{-2\pi in/m}}}=0,$$since the blue part is $0$ but the red part isn't.